# jQuery: Replace window.history entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

I have a site `www.mysite.com/entry/1` with a `div` which opens when I click on a button.

When it opens I make a `window.history.pushState()`, for example:

```
www.mysite.com/entry/1#12345678
```

I can set filter in this opened `div`, so every time I set a filter, the hash value changes and I make a `window.history.pushState("", "", url+newHash);`

When I do this, for example, 10 times, I have 10 different URLs in my `window.history`.

Is it possible to overwrite this, so that I only have the last url-hash value in my history?

The reason is, that when I click on the browser's back button, the url should be `www.mysite.com/entry/1` and I don't want to go through all hash values.

THANKS FOR ANY HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you use `replaceState` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FManipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState()_method), [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#dom-history-replacestate)) rather than `pushState`.

Comment: But how can I only overwrite the urls with has-values and not the other states?

Comment: @Zwen2012: If you use `replaceState`, you replace the topmost history entry. So for instance, you replace the `www.mysite.com/entry/1` entry with `www.mysite.com/entry/1#12345678`. You can't go deeper into the history stack and change data, but based on your question, you shouldn't have to.

Comment: OK, then it was my fault in the question. I need to go back to 'www.mysite.com/entry/1', no matter how often the hash-value-urls changes. So for example, I click 10 filter-> 10 hash vlues in the histroy. And when I now click on browser histroy back i want to go to 'www.mysite.com/entry/1'

Comment: @Zwen2012: Then just use `replaceState` when the URL already has a hash in it.

Comment: Sorry I totally missunterstood the function of replaceState. Now I have it and it works. THANKS!